# Rolling a dice twice, (1,1) = 1/36 not 2/36? (Generalized Counting Principle confusion)

Tags: probability, combinatorics, factorial, dice

[image: picture of sample space example]

So I am confused over why the sample space of rolling a red die and green die results in (1,4) being different from (4,1), but there can only be one (1,1). Why can't there be (1 -red, 1-green) and (1-green, 1-red), if order matters?

In addition, does the generalized counting principle always account for all outcomes possible? I am not sure if the generalized counting principle is counting total number of outcomes where order matters, or order does not matter. It seems that it changes depending on the problem, so I am confused on how to properly apply the generalized counting principle.

For example, my textbook says:
Let E 1 , E 2 , . . . , E k be sets
with n 1 , n 2 , . . . , n k elements, respectively. Then there are n 1 × n 2 × n 3 × · · · × n k ways
in which we can, first, choose an element of E 1 , then an element of E 2 , then an element
of E 3 , . . . , and finally an element of E k .

So it seems to me that order matters for the generalized counting principle? Why don't we multiply by k!, because there are also k! ways to order these Ek sets?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The pair $(1,1)$ means that  the red die came up $1$ as did the green die.  Only one way that could happen.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense, but I am confused why the sample space cannot be 72 ordered pairs if color/order matters? Should there be 36 more pairs added to the sample space, and these pairs consist of green dice rolled first, then red -- does the color of the dice change this problem to a permutation?

Comment: @belle The colour of the die doesn't matter. We are just considering every possible event of the form $(x,y)$ where $x,y\in\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ of which there are these $36$.

Comment: The key point is to be clear what events you are considering.  I assumed that your situation concerned the possible outcomes when you roll a pair of dice (one red, one green),.  In that case there are $36$ possible outcomes, as described. If, say, you rolled one die first and then the other, you could get to $72$ if the sequence of the throws mattered.  Usually, that's not something one takes into account, but you could if you wanted to.

Comment: As others have pointed out, ff the order mattered, and there were $72$ outcomes, there would be $2$ outcomes of $(1,1)$. But then the probability of getting both $1$s would still be $\frac{2}{72} = \frac{1}{36}$.

Comment: @Peter Foreman, thanks, so I gather that the (2,1) and (1,2) are the result of two different outcomes when multiplying x*y sample spaces together, rather than taking color into account

Comment: @lulu So when the question defines the dice roll as "red first, green first", the sample space should only necessarily reflect this event scenario, and the "green first, red first" pairs aren't considered because they do not fit the question criteria?

Comment: @DreiCleaner and lulu, thanks again, that really clears up the question for me!

Comment: Even if the dices are not distinguishable, we can treat the situation as if they were and get then the correct result. It is often difficult to count correct combinatorically because we always have to consider which outcomes are considered to be the same and which not. (+1) since this a problem probably many people have with combinatorical exercises.

Comment: To see why you might wish to use a 72 outcome sample space, consider a game where you roll both dice at the same time down a [Pachinko-like](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pachinko) board, so practically whether the red or green die hits first is equally likely. The payoff is the sum of the dice if the red one touches first, and just the value of the red die if the green one touches first. The probability of scoring 4 is 1/8, which you cannot get just by looking at the normal 36 outcome space.